# Android - pass uri/string/int within same class

Tags: java, android

I would like to pass the selected `videoUri` to a inner class(inside same activity).

I tried doing this with `bundle.putString`, I am not sure if I can acheive this with bundle, I was also thinking of doing it with `Intent.putExtra`, but I am not passing it to a new activity?

This is what I tried:

```
@Override
public void OnClickVideo(Uri videoUri) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("MyBundle", videoUri.toString());

    DoAction();

}

private void DoAction() {
    mStringFilePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("MyBundle");

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mStringFilePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

The `Toast` is empty...

---

**My Question:**

Is there a way to pass data/strings within the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass, no need of bundle. A bundle is to transfer between Android components.

```
@Override
public void OnClickVideo(Uri videoUri) {

    DoAction(videoUri.toString());

}

private void DoAction(String videoUri) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), videoUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

or you can directly do in that method itself

```
@Override
public void OnClickVideo(Uri videoUri) {


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), videoUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using in same class means do like this

```
@Override
public void OnClickVideo(Uri videoUri) {

DoAction(videoUri.toString());

}


private void DoAction(String mStringFilePath) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mStringFilePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```